# Syntax React: хочу прояснить момент

Tags: reactjs

```
class App extends React.Component {
   state = {     
   }
   render() {
      ...
   }
}
```

Почему возможен такой формат объявления **state** и чем отличается, когда оно объявлено в конструкторе.

Answer (score 1):

Ничем он не отличается - бабель сам перенесёт присваивание в конструктор.

Comment: У меня почему-то не работает код вида: `state = { products: [] }`. Выдает ошибку (уже не помню какую) в районе `state = `.. Что бы это могло быть?

Comment: @entithat, возможно, вместо бабеля ты его в браузере пробуешь, а пока ещё рано.

Comment: Это ведь экспериментальный синтаксис? Хм, может быть.. Хорошо. Спасибо.

Comment: @entithat, http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/ - написано, что stage 3, в хроме уже под флагом, а бабель с тайпскриптом давно умеют. Скоро примут. А вот сам пропоузал: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields

Answer (score 1):

Такой способ объявления state появился в ES7. 
Можно объявлять и через конструктор, но он обычно используется только в трёх случаях:

1. Вам нужны props для того, чтобы поместить их в state.
2. Вам нравится старый подход ES6
3. Вам нужно использовать debounce или throttle для методов.